# Logging Design Pattern, one log per client vs querying cetralized log

Tags: node.js, express, logging, elastic-stack, scalability

I'm trying to choose between two patterns or maybe even another one that I have yet to consider for handling logging in my application.

I have a nodejs express server serving clients in an auto scaling group.

The goal is to ideally be able to see each user's activity very easily so that I can trouble shoot in production.

Approach 1, centralized logging using ELK to query based on certain json fields such as customerId requestId etc.

Approach 2, create a log filer per customer and query each file as needed.

In both approaches, log files will be rotated.

Creating a log file per customer just doesn't feel right to me especially when considering the scenarios of having millions of customers but in terms of performance...

1. query 1 million files based on customer ID then subsequently query a much smaller file for the information you need

OR

2. query centralized log file filtering results based on customerID etc.

Is one approach significantly better in performance than the other? What is the best practice in the industry at the moment for this scenario and is there a better approach to consider?

Lastly AWS Services seem to charge based on file size that you are querying. As such would one approach be more cost effective than the other?

Comment: From my experience first one is the way to go. With this approach you can search based on whatever you need.For the time being you may need to search only for customerId but later you might need some other data fields for overall health of the system. Performance is related to resources you assign to ELK stack. The solution may effect it but I would say it is not that important. What do you mean exactly by AWS services if it is ELK then its price calculated by server instances + total disk you need(with backups and snapshots etc)+ bandwith.I dont think it makes any difference between 2.

Comment: Thanks for the response! In terms of aws services I meant more specifically integrating with something like cloudwatch insights. I may be misunderstanding their pricing model though. I'm still figuring out where the capabilities of ELK and insights overlap.